# Converting dataframe column values to list

Tags: python, pandas

I have column which consits of values that are lists and some of them are not.
I would like to get dataframe that only consists of rows(so drop non list rows) that have list values.
Current DF column:

```
Column
["a", "b", "c"]
["a"]
a
b
["cc", "dd"]
```

Result:

```
Column
["a", "b", "c"]
["a"]
["cc", "dd"]
```

Comment: `[row for row in df['Column'] if isinstance(row, list)]` is going to be faster than using a `pandas` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isinstance` method for test `list`s with `map` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['Column'].map(lambda x: isinstance(x, list))]
```

If need output only `Column` and possible multiple columns in real data:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['Column'].map(lambda x: isinstance(x, list)), ['Column']]
```

Or like in comment:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Column': [row for row in df['Column'] if isinstance(row, list)]})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column': [["a", "b", "c"],["a"], 'a','b',["cc", "dd"]]})
print(df[df.Column.apply(lambda row: type(row)==list)])
```

Output

```
      Column
0  [a, b, c]
1        [a]
4   [cc, dd]
```